# The intuition behind a matrix of a Hamiltonian?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, reference-request, mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics

We have derived an elegant partition function for a problem which *resembles* a quantized model taking the particles to be *Bosons*. The related Hamiltonian for every $i$th ensemble is there:
$$H_i=\sum_{q=1}^\infty \sigma_{q,i} \; \lambda_q$$
while $q$ and $i$ positive integers.

What we find is that $\sigma_{q,i}$ is an infinite matrix, and we have all elements of this infinite matrix from observations. $\sigma_{q,i}$ contains only positive integers (and zero), it is a lower triangular matrix with all diagonal elements equal zero. The matrix is not random.

I wonder if you can help me to understand where and how such matrices are dealt with in math/physics? Is there a specific name/notation for them? Is there a certain intuition behind of such Hamiltonian and such type of matrix? I want to analyse $\sigma_{q,i}$ further from different point of view.

Thanks

Comment: A lower triangular matrix as a Hamiltonian, really? Hasn’t the Hamiltonian be Hermitian?